# iPad: [[NSURL absoluteURL]pathExtension] not available in 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

I am porting some code over to the iPad and targeting 3.2.  I'm using some 4.0 exclusive code in the -pathExtension method of NSURL.

I handle all web requests differently depending on what the hyperlink points to.  Was there a way to do this before 4.0 came out, or am I just stuck reading the last 4 characters of the URL string with NSRange?

I'm trying to differentiate between .png and .jpg files, if a user wants to browse to either I handle it differently.

This is what I'm doing now but looking for a better way:

```
NSString *path = [[[request URL]absoluteURL]path];
NSInteger pathLength = [path length];
NSInteger lengthToPeriod = pathLength - 3;
NSRange extensionRange = NSMakeRange(lengthToPeriod,3);
NSString *extension = [path substringWithRange:extensionRange];
```

Comment: Bear in mind that comparing file extensions is no guarantee of what file type you'll get back. You want to wait until the NSURLResponse comes in and then decide based on its MIME type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, -[NSString pathExtension] is available on iOS 2.0 and later.  Are you getting a compiler error when you try to compile a line like this in 3.2?

```
[[[[request URL] absoluteURL] path] pathExtension];
```

Comment: No because I was too busy trying to find something in the NSURL documentation!  Thanks for your help, friend